# Sandboxed app: How to create applicationScriptsDirectory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to build an app (in the macOS Sandbox) thats runs Apple Scripts from applicationScriptsDirectory. If directory exist all is fine. But if I delete this directory — my app can't to create it manually (I don't have permissions to create a folder in the Application Scripts).

Is there any way to create that default folder automatically?

Answer (score 3):

A sandboxed app has permissions to create its application scripts directory.
The method `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` of `FileManager` retrieves the URL and creates the directory if necessary.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let scriptsFolderURL = try! fileManager.url(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

Comment: And when I trying to run your example I've got a fatal error: **fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file**

Comment: Weird. I created two projects using the application scripts folder without any problems. Have you changed the privileges of the parent folder `~/Library/Application Scripts/`? It's supposed to be `you:staff 700`

Comment: Permissions looks fine:  755   iam:staff  :-(   File access (below the App Sandbox): User Selected File Read/Write (I thinks it's fine too).

Comment: Even if the privileges seem sufficient 755 is wrong. All standard user folders in macOS are supposed to have 700

Comment: Changed the privileges to 700 — the fatal error is still here :-( [link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/9f1a85b3649a439ea64d362854579bb8.png)

Comment: By default every application has access to the application scripts directory. It seems that the privileges on your computer are mixed up.

Comment: Tried to clear all privileges via OnyX app. The error is still there :-(  But thanks any way!

Comment: did you try your code on another computer or with the guest account?

Comment: @mahaltertin I tried with the guest account. For the start — the folder of the App is exist. If I delete it and try to run the code — app crashed :-(

Comment: Do you have a developer account? I got one, maybe that makes the difference.

Comment: @vadian  Yep, I've got a developer account. I already ask Apple's technical support this question — will see what they answer :-)

Comment: @MaxVecheslavov Same problem here, Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that is not possible under macOS 10.12 to create the `Application Scripts` folder, but it works on 10.11. While it has before possible to create the bundle scripts directory and copy files in it, it is not allowed for Sandboxed apps, maybe Apple added a restriction for this now.

It is not perfect, but seems to work:

```
lazy var scriptsFolderURL: URL = {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    var scriptsFolder: URL!
    do {
        scriptsFolder = try manager.url(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    } catch {
        scriptsFolder = manager.urls(for: .applicationScriptsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    }
    return scriptsFolder
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

A Sandboxed app should have permission to create its own Application Scripts directory, even without a write-entitlement/bookmark to that location (which is needed to actually copy scripts into the directory).

However, there seems to be a bug/quirk around this experience. If the Application Scripts directory is deleted, your app may be unable to recreate it. I just hit this issue in my app.

Deleting the app's container seems to reset the permissions and allow creation of the Applications Script directory on the next run.

Source:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79384

> Though it's definitely not an ideal solution, it seems like manually removing the container corresponding to your application's bundle identifier in ~/Library/Containers, and then relaunching your app causes the corresponding Application Scripts subfolder to get created.